# get index of a element with jquery

Tags: jquery

Well, i'm using `index()` to get the current index of a element and then using it with `eq` and `gt` selectors to enable and disable inputs.

but, i believe that `index()` only work by searching the sibling elements. So, the way as my html structure are now, the index is not helping me. How can i make this work?

```
var $cascade = $(".cascade-discount-2"); // switch to 1
$("input", $cascade).on("keyup", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    index = $this.index();
    if($.isNumeric($this.val())){
        $("input", $cascade).eq(index+1).attr("disabled", false);
    }else{
        $("input:gt("+index+")", $cascade).attr("disabled", true);
    } 
});
```

html structure that dos not work:

```
<div class='sep cascade-discount-1'>
<div class='bla'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="0"  />
</div>
<div class='bla'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="0" disabled='disabled'/>
</div>
<div class='bla'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="0" disabled='disabled'/>
</div>
```

[**here is a fiddle with a working and not working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jyb77/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The no-argument variant of .index() will the index of the element with respect its siblings, in your case all input elements are the first child of its parent.

But there is a second variant which takes a argument

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

```
var $cascade = $(".cascade-discount-1"),
    $inputs = $cascade.find('input'); // switch to 1
$inputs.on("keyup", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    index = $inputs.index(this);
    if ($.isNumeric($this.val())) {
        $("input", $cascade).eq(index + 1).attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("input:gt(" + index + ")", $cascade).attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jR224/)

Answer (score 2):

The code written by you will suits for the second sort of `DOM` structure, Because all of those `input` elements are the `siblings` each other. But in the first structure of `DOM` you just wrapped all of those `input` elements inside another `div`. So that your code will return `0` always.

Try this,

```
    var $cascade = $(".cascade-discount-1");

    $("input", $cascade).on("keyup", function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        index = $(this).closest('div').index();
        if($.isNumeric($this.val())){
            $("input", $cascade).eq(index+1).attr("disabled", false);
        }else{
            $("input:gt("+index+")", $cascade).attr("disabled", true);
        } 
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jyb77/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the index of the parent element may help:

```
 index = $this.parent().index();
```